# How to run several commands on precommit with husky npm module?

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint, stylelint, husky

I use husky to check JS before commit.
In my package.json i have

```
"scripts": {
    "lintStyles": "stylelint app/**/*.scss",
    "fixStylesLinting": "stylelint app/**/*.scss --fix",
    "lintJS": "eslint app/**/*.js",
    "fixJSLinting": "eslint --fix app/**/*.js",
    "precommit": "npm run lintJS"
  }
```

It works, what i don't understand is how can i run both lintJS, lintStyles commands.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

to include more than one script add `&&`for ex:

`precommit: npm run lint:sass && npm run lint:js`

Comment: Yep, that's what i actually have.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint:scss": "stylelint app/**/*.scss",
  "fixStylesLinting": "stylelint app/**/*.scss --fix",
  "lint:js": "eslint app/**/*.js",
  "fixJSLinting": "eslint --fix app/**/*.js",
  "precommit": "npm run lint:*"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to run multiple hooks on single pre-commit you need to do like this

```
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"
```

similarly for other hook add:

```
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm run ban"
```

so that the file looks like this in the `husky` folder:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
npm run ban
```

Then in `package.json` add following

```
"pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run ban"
```

separated by `&&`

Comment: Why are you using `.husky/pre-commit` file and `pre-commit` attribute in `package.json? Aren't they the same?

Comment: Doesn't commands in `.husky/pre-commit` also need the `&&` to prevent shadowing the previous commands escape codes?